# YouTube won't accept login/account

Tags: ios, appletv

I've upgraded my apple tv to ios 5.1 only to have it now reject my youtube login.  I've previously had this same Apple TV login just fine, but I accidentally hit log out.  It just gives me the "This account can not be used with Apple TV" error.  I've tried multiple login types.

- Youtube Username
- Google Email Address
- Normal Password
- 2 Factor Auth Password (after entering the normal password first and it failing, hoping to trigger the 2 logins required for Google sometimes)
- I even created a brand new YouTube account without 2 factor auth and it does the same thing.  Using a simple password even.
- Reset All Settings on the AppleTV
- Tried a restore, but it failed. I plan to try another one, but dread hooking it up to iTunes.

I'm on my last attempt and I feel it likely won't work.  Any ideas?  Anyone willing to logout and try to replicate ;) ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the entire youtube app wasn't able to connect at all. No Featured Videos or anything. Makes sense why it couldn't log in. I ended up trying multiple reboots and nothing working. A full restore fixed it though. Annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else with a similar problem might appreciate this answer, even though you've found the reason for your own problem.

If you can connect to YouTube but can't log in using your own password and you have [2-step authentication](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en) enabled on your Google account, you have to go you [Google Account Authorized Access settings](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en), scroll to the bottom and generate an Application-specific password. This creates a unique password for use with that specific service and will only be shown once.

HTH someone else :)